# APK generator for android apps

Tags: android, apk

I plan to write a stand-alone GUI application using which I can generate APK files to be installed on an android handset.

The generated android application screens would have a fixed layout. While running the application, the layout has to be populated and filled from the database which I add to the application. The table fields would be same though the contents are different for each database. ie; each time I generate an APK, the only variable that has to go into the application is the database.

Can someone please let me know whether I can achieve this? If yes, please let me know as to how to proceed with this.

Any queries, clarifications, please let me know.

Any help is appreciated

Comment: are you planning a desktop application ? or do you want your code that generates APKs to run on the phone ?

Comment: @Madushan: plannig to write a GUI desktop application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are only changing the database, you can include your source code with the GUI, also include the Android apk tools, use scripts to run the apk building and signing after you have changed the database (which will just be some type of replace in /assets/)

You can learn all about manually signing from the command line here: (i.e. scripting)

http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#releasemode

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you only need the database to be different. Compile the code to APK. Your GUI application will create a new database, and will replace the one inside the APK. You can access the APK file same as a ZIP or a JAR file. You will need a ZIP framework for this. (There's a framework called [DotNetZip](http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/) for .NET which I find very useful for this type of work. Don't know any frameworks for Java off the top of my head.) Note that if you have any code signing, that has to happen after inserting the new DB.

**Option 2**

Depending on your use case, if the app can identify it-self in some way (by the user/ credentials/ device ID .etc.) you can make it download the database/data necessary on the first run.